# Using VLOOKUP to match each value of cell (cell has multiple values separated by comma) in table A with values in table B

Tags: excel

**Problem Statement:**

Table 1: It has multiple values in each cell of Column B.

Table 2: Is the reference table Employees and their category is mentioned

[image]

**Output Required:**

Table 3: This is what the output should look like, i.e. each column (C to F) shows the total no. of Sr, Jr, Cont and Int in that row

[image]